How is a Palestinian State to be recognized by Spain defined?
The talks about two-state solution came up several times since Oct. 7 but last Tuesday, Spanish Prime Minister Pedro Sánchez stated that Spain will recognize the Palestinian Statehood by July this year (2024). The Palestinian people inhabit Israel, the West Bank, and the Gaza strip.
How exactly would the Palestinian State to be recognized by Spain be defined? Like: where does it start; where does it end; what are its borders?
Source: https://www.ft.com/content/13eec547-85db-4bcc-bd1c-07bb33b9bfdf

Any reason to suppose it would be any different from the Palestinian state as recognised by the UNGA ie 1967 borders?

@JamesK Quite possibly true.  But that doesn't take away from the question's interest, as it is not that obvious to the average person reading the question (and I include myself in that lack of knowledge on that first read).

It isn't obvious to me that this question has an answer yet. Presumably, one of the reasons that an announcement was deferred until July is that Spain hasn't figured out the fine details of its Prime Minister's proposal yet. If there is an answer, great, and eventually there will be one. But at this point, any answer would probably be mere speculation.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica  Sure.  I'm not personally very interested in this question, but perhaps it could prompt the OP to include some prior research.

@JamesK Well, your stating there is an obvious answer - 1967 - is at odds with ohwilleke's statement that it is too early to tell at this time.  But surely, what Palestine's border would look like, and what the process will be to arrive at those borders, given Israel's refusal to contemplate such a thing, will be most interesting.   1967 would be solid, but remember that plenty of folk also fantasize about "from the river to the sea" these days.  July is also not far away and this exact question is bound to surface early on in discussions of Spain's recognition procedures in their parliament.

I'd point out that borders needn't be universally agreed upon for a state to exist, or Spain itself would be in trouble. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Territorial_disputes_of_Spain (Notably, they claim Gibraltar.)

@ceejayoz I guess then in the Spanish eyes, a Palestinian state already exists (from July on). That kind of validates the question. One would probably like to know what this kind of part-existing, part-not-existing state actually looks like.

Henry Kissinger once remarked that Israel has no foreign policy, only domestic politics. This fully applies to many nations, arguably even more to the democratic ones, where the politicians are dependent on the support/votes of the population.
Spanish intention to recognize the Palestinian state certainly serves to score some points with the Spanish, many of whom support Palestinians (or Gaza, or Hamas) and oppose Zionism (or Israel, or Jews altogether), but likely to deserve only scorn of the Palestinians. Indeed, the outcomes of such a recognition would be to make the Israeli position even more recalcitrant (the Israeli Parliament has only recently passed a resolution expressly rejecting such diktats), and possibly to entrench the two-state solution as the only possible outcome - which, ironically, may mean no truly viable/sovereign Palestinian state ever (if we take into account the Facts on the ground.) Hamas and its supporters will be equally displeased.
As for the documents governing Israel's legitimacy and its borders, the two main ones are:

UN General Assembly adopted the Plan as Resolution 181 (II) (The Partition Plan, previewing creating of  a Jewish state alongside a Palestinian one)
United Nations Security Council Resolution 242, colloquially referred to as 1967 borders, which are really 1949 ceasefire linens (also known as Green line.)

In practice, the Spanish recognition will be probably intentionally vague, as to allow the necessary adjustments and the smoothing out the frictions with Israel after the Gaza war is over. It will however prop the Palestinian Authority - at the expense of Hamas and whatever government Israel is planning to set up in Gaza - by giving its representatives in Spain a status of embassy. Propping the PA is also the US policy - and the Spanish probably aim to get some stroking from the Uncle Sam as well.
Related:
Catalan independence movement
Basque Country independence
Galician independence movement
Alhambra decree
Sephardic Jews
Appendix: Problems of the two-state-solution and alternative solutions
The vision known as two-state-solution dates back nearly four decades, when it was adopted by the Palestinian liberation organization (PLO) and later codified within the Oslo framework in the early 1990. It previews creation of a Palestinian state within the part of the British mandate Palestine, which was not controlled by Israel prior to June 5, 1967, with possible small territorial adjustments. In the decades that have passed, there have been many physical, political, and demographic developments which likely make this form of solution impossible. To mention the principal ones:
Territorial contiguity of the future Palestinian state
There is about half a million Israelis living in the West Bank, with the settlements located at the strategic points, dividing the WB into separate "cantons". This supposedly makes impossible a contiguous Palestinian state (I say "supposedly" since I am not an expert, not to bias anyone's judgement.) There have been attempts to paper over this problem by saying that Israel would keep "large settlement blocks" and/or compensate the Palestinians by "land swamps". These do not solve the problem of contiguity and possibly even worsen it. Besides, the land swaps may mean exchanging fertile lands for worthless desert or something like that. Removing half a million settlers, some of whom are by now indigenous to the WB, is also a questionable solution, which could be qualified as a "population transfer" or even "ethnic cleansing".

Palestine is already a failed state
Palestinian authority has markedly failed in state building. While the economic troubles and absence of the basic government services can be blamed on Israel, the two elephants in the room are the endemic corruption and the absence of the rule of law. The PA have systematically failed to prevent the armed groups to launch attacks against its neighboring state (Israel), and a significant part of the Palestinian state is currently controlled by such an armed group (Gaza), denying the PA government and the international agreements.
This is not unlike the situation in Lebanon, where Hezbollah is represented in the parliament, but otherwise run the state regardless of the opinion of politicians. Allowing Israel to have the security control over the future Palestinian state is thus rather different from what it means, e.g., for Andorra - it means that Israel should be able to carry out anti-terrorist activities in the midst of the Palestinian population... as it does now.
Overpopulation
The Palestinian population in the WB and Gaza has increased nearly twofold since the two state solution became actuality. Gaza has the same population density as London... but without the countryside for agriculture. Thus, it is questionable whether the Palestinian state could even sustain the lives of its citizens without international aid.
(image source)

Refugees
There are about 5 million Palestinian refugees in the world - nearly as many as the populations of the WB and Gaza taken together (although there is some overlap.) About half of these are Jordanian citizens who may prefer to remain in Jordan, some live in the West or elsewhere in the Arab world, integrated into their host countries, some are already living in the WB and Gaza and will presumably stop being considered refugees once the Palestinian state is defined. However, about a million live in Egypt, Syria and Lebanon, with no path to naturalization. In Lebanon the Palestinians are confined to the refugee camps, prohibited from owning property or business, and from working outside the refugee camps. These will want to immigrate to the Palestinian state, contributing to its overpopulation. Note that western recognition does little to help this population (in fact, it is largely ignored by the west.)
Possible alternative solutions 
There's no magic solution to the Palestinian problems. I note the most well known proposals:
One-state-solution
There are different versions of these, ranging from a unitary state where Jews and Palestinians have equal rights, to bi-national state - with guaranteed representation to major ethnic and/or religious groups (Lebanon is an obvious but uninspiring example), to Islamic state with non-Muslims tolerated as dhimmi. Perfect in theory, such a state is likely to be unstable, resulting in a civil war, and/or a new genocide, or a failed state - Lebanon is again an example here on all counts. There are also formidable legal problems, as the Israeli and Palestinian national rights are enshrined in the already cited UN resolutions, and in Israeli international recognition an membership in the UN and other organizations.
Finally, the very essence of Zionism is that the security of Jewish people cannot he guaranteed by no one but the Jewish people themselves - as actions or inaction by non-Jews have shown on many occasions over the last two millennia, and the Arab hostility to Jewish presence in the middle east has done little to diminish this sentiment. So Israelis would fight rather than let anyone rule them or impose a solution - in other words, international pressure, sanctions and boycott are more likely to result in a new Warsaw ghetto uprising rather than the end of the occupation.
Three-state-solution
This means returning to pre-1967 situation, where the WB was a part of Jordan, while Gaza was administered by Egypt. The Palestinians would then become respectively Jordanians and Egyptians, and granted the full rights and the freedom of movement in these countries. The refugees elsewhere could be naturalized as well in their host countries. This solution is appealing from the humanitarian point of view. It is problematic, because it denies the Palestinians the right to self-determination (no Palestinian state.) It is also likely to be opposed by the countries concerned - Jordan would become a country with Palestinian majority, ruled by a non-Palestinian King, and spectrum of a new Black September rising. Egypt already has difficulties managing Bedouin population in Sinai, and Gaza would only compound it.
Greater Gaza
This is a far-fetched solution, marred by its recent association with the supposed expulsion of Palestinians from Gaza to Egypt. But in its original form it has some appeal. It implies Egypt ceding a part of the Sinai territory, about 4-6 times the size of Gaza and adjacent to it, forming a contiguous Palestinian state. Presumably, Egypt would be compensated by some worthy Israeli territory and economic and political incentives. This solution does give Palestinians a state, and a viable one... but it has the symbolism of giving up on their historical homeland. It also means displacing or subjugating to Palestinians of some of the Sinai Bedouin. While the dispossession of Sinai Bedouin is an ongoing (and sometimes violent) process, it is largely overlooked by the west, like many human rights violations... but it will probably attract more attention, once Israel is involved.
Update
Al-Jazeera also points out that the current pro-Palestinian stance is prompted by seeking domestic support of Catalan and Basque leftist, who traditionally associate their independence struggle with that of the Palestinians:

Cristina Lopez, a public relations executive from Valencia, believes geopolitics have become subsumed into domestic issues in Spain.
“Like most, if not all, aspects of life in Spain, there is a domestic political subtext behind it and the conflict in Israel and Palestine is no different,” she said.
“Sanchez’s latest words are sending a message to his coalition partners, Basque and Catalan nationalists, whose support he relies on to govern.”
Spain’s inconclusive July elections meant Sanchez was forced to enlist the support of pro-independence parties in the Basque Country and Catalonia to form a minority left-wing coalition government.


I would hardly characterize a border based on the 1967 UN resolution as a "diktat".  Nor is it calling into question Israel's right to exist - within its portion of the 1967 lines, with the possibility of land swaps.  Palestinians' rights to a state  (quite possibly with externally enforced peacefulness) - should not be dependent on Israeli domestic politics.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica as far as I understand, they mean by "dictat" imposing border on a sovereign state, regardless of whether it agrees or not.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica as for the rest - let's avoid repeating decades old clichés. Signing a piece of paper is not answer to Palestinian problems - just a cynical way to silence western conscience.

careful about "Western conscience" arguments.  they get used in both directions ;-)

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica also the colonizer mentality, which makes them feel that they have the moral high ground to judge Jews, Arabs and the rest of the world.

@RogerV. The is one of the best answers on a difficult subject that I've seen in SE.

I'm not in tune to the specifics of the discussions in Spain, but for reference, a Western European country that did that relative recently was Sweden in 2014. They were not too clear on borders though.

Sweden considered that criteria in international law for recognizing a Palestinian state "are met,"  Sweden's Foreign Minister Margot Wallstrom said. Although the borders are not defined, there is a government that can "show inner and outer control."
Wallstrom wrote that "Sweden has earlier recognized states - Croatia in 1992 and Kosovo in 2008 - although they actually lacked control over parts of their territory. Like them, Palestine is a special case."

BTW, that decision was taken by left-wing Swedish government. The current Swedish government is on the opposite end of the spectrum and they called the decision "premature and unfortunate", but didn't quite 'take it back':

“The decision to recognize Palestine in 2014 was premature and unfortunate. However, the decision has been taken and this government doesn’t plan to revoke it.”

Also, going back to some debates in Sweden a couple of years before the FM decision (and when the left-wing wasn't yet in power), some of the arguments were indeed as to what borders should they recognize:

In parliamentary foreign policy debates on 25 October, 2011 (Riksdagen, 2011) and 15 February, 2012 (Riksdagen, 2012), Bildt explained his reasoning. Control of territory was, he argued, a basic criteria which the Palestinians could not fulfil as Israel was the ultimate power in the occupied territories. He warned that one should not ignore the reality of the occupation and think that the Palestinians actually exercised sovereignty. Palestinian officials could be democratically elected one day and arrested by Israel the next. While he hoped that circumstances would change to allow recognition, policy could not ignore this frustrating reality. Sweden would continue to work for a “strong and unified European policy” towards the conflict, building on the example of the 2009 statement (Riksdagen, 2012).
The opposition coalition composed of the Social Democrats, the Greens, and the Leftists argued differently.  In an op-ed to the newspaper Svenska Dagbladet published that day to coincide with the debate, the opposition leaders argued that to follow the government’s logic was to put all the power in the hands of the Israeli occupiers (Löfven et al, 2012). In their view, the three main international legal criteria for statehood (borders, a permanent population, and government) were in fact met. In line with UNSC Resolution 242, the borders of a Palestinian state would be based on the so-called 4 June, 1967 borders which demarcate the occupied Palestinian territories. Although these are disputed borders and are subject to negotiation with Israel, this has not prevented in the international community from recognising the state of Israel.

And in fact, Bild himself was more flexible on Kosovo:

Indeed, in his justification of the recognition of Kosovo, Foreign Minister Bildt (2008) stated clearly that the decision was not based on the traditional Montevideo criteria. Instead, he emphasised the broader political and conflict context, and the deadlock between Brussels, Moscow, and Washington which made agreement impossible to reach. Kosovo’s political and economic development would be a considerable challenge, but one that the international community would help them face.

And Wallström then built on that:

Recognition of Palestinian statehood was not seen as a substitute for a negotiated peace, but would in fact contribute to one by addressing the asymmetry between the parties and enabling negotiations between two states rather than an occupier and the occupied. Recognition was in many ways an effort to keep the dwindling prospect of a two-state solution alive: “there are those who will argue that today’s decision is premature. If anything, I fear it is too late.” (Wallström, 2014)

But AFAICT, borders were not discussed again in 2014.

OTOH when Iceland did the same in 2011, their parliament authorized the FM to do in the 1967 borders.

On 29 November 2011, the parliament of Iceland passed a resolution that authorized the government to officially recognize the state of Palestine within the 1967 borders. The resolution was passed without opposing votes, although several opposition MPs abstained. Össur Skarphéðinsson, Minister for Foreign Affairs of Iceland, formally declared Iceland's recognition of the state of Palestine on December 15, 2011.

Interestingly, from a note on the latter, the executive didn't seem to take a position on the borders itself, but passed the parliamentary note as such the PA:

Össur Skarphéðinsson, Minister for Foreign Affairs of Iceland, and Dr. Riad Malki, the Foreign Minister of Palestine, today formally confirmed the establishment of full diplomatic relations between Iceland and Palestine. The Icelandic Foreign Minister presented to Dr. Malki a diplomatic note stating that as resolved with the Parliamentary Resolution of 29 November 2011 the Government of Iceland has, as of 15 December 2011, recognized Palestine as an independent and sovereign state within the pre-1967 Six Day War borders.

So it's quite possible to leave a degree of ambiguity on the borders in various ways.
Also, once a state recognizes some borders of another, that doesn't really preclude them from agreeing to something else in the future, i.e. none of the recognitions prevent the PA the from agreeing some kind of territorial reduction or swaps in exchange for Israeli recognition etc. Those kinds of voluntary deals are implicitly ack'd by other countries, unless there's controversy of the legitimacy of the gov'ts making that decision, etc.
